# ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery) returns null

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

Steps to Reproduce
Create a flutter app. Try and use the most basic functionality of the image_picker plugin.

Expected results:

When you select an image from the gallery, it should return something to your application. A file, or location. Anything really.

Actual results:

Nothing. The gallery launches. You select an image. Gallery goes away, nothing is returned to the app at all. Just leaves null.

My code

```
Future getImage() async {
  var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  customImageFile = image.toString();
  print('customImageFile: ' + customImageFile);
}
```

Output from code

```
customImageFile: null
```

Plugin Version

image_picker: 0.6.5

Flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1098], locale en-AU)
• Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at c:\flutter
• Framework revision 27321eb (4 months ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
• Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
• Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
• Android SDK at C:\Installations\AndroidSDK
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Installations\AndroidSDK
• Java binary at: C:\Installations\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
• Android Studio at C:\Installations\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
• Dart plugin version 191.8593
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
• SM G970F • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: print('customImageFile: ' + image.runtimeType.toString());  results in Null.

Answer (score 2):

```
Future getImage() async {
  var image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  customImageFile = File(image.path);
  print('customImageFile: ' + customImageFile);
}
```

Flutter 2

Answer (score 1):

You should typecast image variable as File:

```
var image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery) as File;
```

Answer (score 0):

The image_picker returns null on IOS simulator on M1 Macs. This is a problem that is still not resolved. Use a physical device. Your code seems correct.

Comment: For real? :( That's bad.. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Yes. The only workaround is to use a physical device

Comment: I found on github that you can use IOS Version 13.7 and it indeed works.

Comment: It didn't work for me on ios 14.7 and there is also a GitHub issue regarding this

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71943     https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70436

Answer (score -2):

> flutter

you need to create future function.
store the result in a variable of File bcz it will return
the image Path

```
Future<File> pickImage(ImageSource source) async{
    File testImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    setState(() {
      pickedImage = testImage;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Nitin0310.   I will edit my code as I do have this in a future, I just didn't paste that section.   Let me know if this still looks incorrect to you after the edit.

Comment: I have tested this using your exact code, and called with pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);   This still results in a null result.  pickedImage returns null after selecting image from the gallery.